# Changing the location of the User Table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm learning Laravel 5.6, and I want to be able to use my existing `user` table which is present in another database.  It's still called users, but it has lots and lots of data in it.

In order to achieve this I really need to do two things:

- Have Laravel use the `users` database in a different database to the default one
- Change the method for encrypting passwords to my inferior way (until I actually get round to using bcrypt for all my users)

So.  For the point one I currently have my Laravel `.env` database variables pointing to my test database, `laravel`.  What I'd like to is to just have the user lookup / authentication use the table `users` in my `shop` database.  So instead of `laravel.users` it would be `shop.users`.

As I mentioned before I haven't been using great encryption but until I get round to properly encrypting everyones passwords I'd need Laravel to use my own encryption method, (which I know isnt as secure) But the hashing is as follows:

`$hash = hash('sha256',$salt.$password.$salt);`

Is this possible / how can I achieve these two things?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to Laravel, but I'm pretty sure that the easiest way to achieve this is to import your existing shop database to the new Laravel database.

From what I've gathered, there isn't any official support for this but it should be quite simple to write a small script that transfers all the data from the old DB to the new one using [regular php sql queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) and just looping it all into the new one.

Or just use some [unofficial package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator).

Comment: Yeah, I could do that but i've got lots of subdomains and web apps that all point to a single user database, and I can't duplicate them all across each database.  Nor do I want a huge database with every single table in one place, that would just be messy.

Comment: @Chud37 Ah I see. I just checked the Eloquent documentation and it seems like you can define another database connection in your application and then choose which models should use which connection. Which, if i've understood it correctly, is exactly what you're looking for. :) 
Search for "Connection"
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#basic-usage

Comment: I found the answer, it was a lot less complicated than I thought! I've post the answer in response.  Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I've found the answer to my question by simply modifying the file `\config\auth.php`.  There was an array commented out that looked like this:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users2',
    // ],  
],
```

I un-commented out the sections and set the table to users2.  That worked fine.  However that was still loading from the same database.  So I changed the `table` string to: `shop.users2` and it worked straight away.

Simple!  I couldnt find any documentation on that though, but I am glad it worked.